# How to get google earth to display all placemarks in a large kml file

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have created a kml file that can be played back in google earth.  During play back the placemarks stop appearing before play back of the file is complete.  It is a placemark for a moving vehicle over an 8 hour period for every 0.1 of a second, could be up to 294,000.
Is there a way to get google earth to display all place marks in a large file like this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use an extremely simple png file to display the placemarks. Just a dot or two. Use StyleUrl instead of repeating the style thousands of times. Or, depending on the nature of your file, you can get incredible savings by using a tessellated line instead of a series of Track Points. I wrote a program to simplify my kml files. They aren't large but they are numerous and so as a group they were slow to draw. You can run my free program by sending an email with kml in the subject line to KmlFixer@Gmail.com. You'll get an automated response with directions. It's pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 3):

You could display up to 294K placemarks at the same time but such a large KML file usually results in performance problems and sometimes rendering issues.

In a [test KML generator](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/bigKml.html), there were serious problems with loading a single KML file with 500K placemarks. A similar test with 100K placemarks had a long startup delay (~2 minutes) but worked smoothly after that. These numbers provide a rough order to the limit of features in a single KML file.

Suggest breaking up the placemarks into something like 1-hour chunks then have a parent KML file using [network links](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink) to load all the chunks. The NetworkLinks each should have a [TimeSpan](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#timespan) for its respective time segment. Then only the segment(s) that are active will be loaded and displayed. If performance is still an issue then can break into smaller chunks.

The root KML would look something like this:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <name>Parent Document</name>
    <open>1</open>

    <NetworkLink>
      <name>Group #1</name>
      <TimeSpan>
            <begin>2012-08-12T01:00:00Z</begin>
            <end>2012-08-12T01:59:59Z</end>
      </TimeSpan>
      <Link>
        <href>group_0100.kml</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>

    <NetworkLink>
      <name>Group #2</name>
      <TimeSpan>
            <begin>2012-08-12T02:00:00Z</begin>
            <end>2012-08-12T02:59:59Z</end>
      </TimeSpan>
      <Link>
        <href>group_0200.kml</href>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
    ...
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: I used google takeout for my Location History which resulted in 383K points. Google Earth stutters and breaks completely. I tried NetworkLink but Google Earth still tries to load all of them at once. Is there any way to signal it not to?

Comment: I fixed it with `<visibility>0</visibility>` on the `Folder` and `NetworkLink` nodes. Just hiding `Folder` nodes didn't work.

Comment: @ubershmekel - child features don't inherit the visibility from their parent folders as described in the KML spec. Must add visibility 0 to each NetworkLink to make to not load by default if not using time ranges. Bug listed here:https://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=435